# Cast generic queue elements and process events using derived classes

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I have a main thread that does some work and it delegates an other thread asynchronously to send some data to another process.

I used a generic queue of shared_ptr(T), the main thread pushes into queue and the second thread pops the data and processes it.

I pushes many data types (i.e. shared_ptr(A), shared_ptr(B)) deriving from T.

```
class A : public T{};
class B : public T{};
```

What's the best way (efficient) to know the derived class from the generic type.

PS: Dynamic cast is not the best solution.
The producer sends data type.
The consumer pops the queue and does his job depending on the passed data.
The consumer uses this data when calling a given function.
The consumer should detect the derived class of the passed parameter to delegate the appropriate function to call.

```
void process(shared_ptr<T> ptr)
{
if (type(ptr) == A) do work using A..
if (type(ptr) == B) do staff using B..
...
}
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Off topic but... why do things this way at all?  Why not just have a queue of `std::function<void()>` instances?  The client code pushes tasks on to the queue and the consumer simply dequeues and calls them.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have data to pass from one thread to another.

Comment: And that data can easily be captured by a [`lambda`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) used to initialize the `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example, I didn't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to queuing instances of `std::shared_ptr<T>` you could queue instances of a callable type such as [`std::function<void()>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

```
#include <functional>

using task_type = std::function<void()>;

queue_type<task_type> queue;
```

You state that you want to do something like...

> ```
> if (type(ptr) == A) do work using A..
> if (type(ptr) == B) do staff using B..
> ```

Assuming the two functions in question are `do_work` and `do_stuff` the client code would then be...

```
auto dataA = std::make_shared<A>(...);
queue.enqueue([dataA]()
              {
                  do_work(dataA);
              });
auto dataB = std::make_shared<B>(...);
queue.enqueue([dataB]()
              {
                  do_stuff(dataB);
              });
```

And the consumer code...

```
while (true) {
    try {

        /*
         * Dequeue the next task.
         */
        auto f = queue.dequeue();

        /*
         * Run it.
         */
        f();
    catch (...) {

        /*
         * Handle errors here.
         */
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to run the methode f() with the parameter data.

Comment: Then please edit your question to clarify what it is you're trying to do and also where those extra parameters come from.

Comment: If the consumer executes f(), it will call do_work(dataA) for example ?

Comment: That's correct.  The function to call *and* the data to be passed as a parameter can all be packaged up using the lambda.